# Rails: Calling a function in asset pipeline from JS response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Somewhere in the application.js I am compiling I have this object and function:

> chosen.coffee

```
Foo = 
  do_this: ->
    $('.slider').slider()

$ ->
  Foo.do_this()
```

This calls JQueryUI and turns one of my divs into a slider. Then user does stuff and re-renders that html.  My question is, how do I get to call this function from a response.js.erb?

> response.js.erb

```
  $('big_body_thing').append('<div class="slider"></div>')
  Foo.do_this??????
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below code at the end of 'chosen.coffee' file to export `Foo` :

```
root = exports ? this
root.Foo = Foo
```